# How to revert ReadOnly permission changes on AppData folder?

Tags: file-permissions, windows-11, appdata

**Background**

I have Windows 11 Pro on a Lenevo Thinkpad T14.

Today, I was trying to install some software. Long story short, I got an error that said "Cannot write to AppData folder", so being the genius I am, I went straight to the AppData folder in `C:\Users\me\AppData`, right-clicked `Properties`, and unchecked the `Read-only` attribute. As Windows was processing my request, I continued searching around Google and found several people warn against what I was doing. So I canceled my request, rechecked the `Read-only` attribute, and clicked `Apply`.

Then, almost everything stopped working. On Chrome, all my accounts were signed out (I assume because Chrome couldn't access its AppData...). My file explorer would not let me access many of my files. As a result, I couldn't even navigate to the AppData folder to again uncheck the `Read-only` attribute.

I was finally able to uncheck the `Read-only` attribute by using the file explorer and manually typing in the path to the AppData folder, rather than clicking to it. Everything seems to be working as it was before...

**Question**

Finally to my question:

What should I do now? The folder AppData was originally `Read-only`. When I removed and then added back the `Read-only` attribute, everything stopped working. Now I have the `Read-only` attribute unchecked and things are working OK. How can I revert my system back to the way it was? Is it unsafe or bad to have the `Read-only` attribute unchecked?

Comment: Do you have a restore point you can revert to?

Comment: I do have one but I have some files with changes from the past day or two that I'd like to keep. Should I email myself those files and then restore?

Comment: Also, I am using Windows Subsystem for Linux. Does a system restore affect files in my WSL environment the same way it affects all other files? By that I mean, will a system restore simply roll-back my WSL files to the restore point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read Only was only applied to SOME of the folders inside AppData. You can see this because the checkmark was grey, not solid black.

So, you began by removing appropriate permissions, partially, before canceling this.

Then, when you clicked to apply Read Only, you were applying that not to the files or folders it had before, but to ALL the files and folders.

There is no easy way to restore file permissions outside a Restore Point, or by creating a new user profile. Because you only adjusted permissions on your AppData folder, you've only messed up your current profile. Create a new profile and it'll probably be just fine.

Comment: The only thing I'm still curious about is whether it would be OK for me to leave the folder as it is now -- with the ReadOnly attribute unchecked.

Comment: @nwsteg - No; It won't be "ok" for you to leave the permissions that way.  If you can't use applications, that use AppData to store local application data, then you won't be able to run those applications.

Comment: No, file security serves a variety of functions, some mundane, but many critical to system function, to security, etc. Perhaps most seriously, you've now got a system where your personal application data (that's that's in AppData) is open to being modified in ways the system does not intend it to be, which means the system will not be able to control or monitor how that data is modified or accessed. Your system is broken, and your data is at risk. It may not be obvious, but it is true.